# why my "onChange" function is not performing?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```js
export function UpdateData(props){


    return(
        <div>
            <div className='updateForm'>
                <form>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Your ID:</label>
                        <input name="id" type="text" defaultValue={props.usersData._id} autoComplete="off" className="form-control" readOnly></input>
                        <label>Enter your name:</label>
                        <input name="name" type="text" defaultValue={props.usersData.name} autoComplete="off" placeholder="Enter your name here....." className="form-control"
                        onChange={(e)=>console.log(e.target.value)}></input>
                        <label>Enter your age:</label>
                        <input name="age" type="text" defaultValue={props.usersData.age} autoComplete="off" placeholder="Enter your age here....." className="form-control"
                        onChange={(e)=>console.log(e.target.value)}></input>
                        <label>Enter your city:</label>
                        <input name="city" type="text" defaultValue={props.usersData.city} autoComplete="off" placeholder="Enter your city here....." className="form-control"
                        onChange={(e)=>console.log(e.target.value)}></input>
                        <br/>
                        <button className="btn" id="myButton2">Save Update</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I want to console out the changes of the input field, but "onChange" function is not performing accordingly. I have used document.getElementById("updateCont").innerHTML=ReactDOMServer.renderToString();
to send the data.

Comment: What do you mean by _"function is not performing accordingly"_? Do the logs appear? Do you get any errors?

Comment: `ReactDOMServer.renderToString` renders the markup on the server, meaning any client-side functions (`onChange`) won't work. You need to render your app client-side.

Comment: oky....so any suggestion for how to send props without ReactDOMServer.renderToString ,
I need to use innerHTML @bryce

Comment: @SOHAMHAZRA `ReactDOM.render(<UpdateData />, document.getElementById("updateCont"));`

Comment: Don't use `innerHTML` when rendering react.

Comment: Thank You so much
do I need any library to import ? @bryce

Comment: @SOHAMHAZRA ReactDOM

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to declare a handleChange function and then set it to the onChange attribute?